# Atributo de classe no construtor

Tags: javascript, construtor, escopo-de-variáveis, ecmascript-6

Consigo acessar um atributo da classe dentro do escopo do construtor, porém fora dá '*undefined*'

```
constructor(errorAlert){
  this._errorAlert = errorAlert;
}
```

Se, por exemplo, no código acima, eu der `console.log()` no parâmetro recebido e no atributo, ambos retornar o mesmo valor, porém, quando vou usar o atributo no restante da classe, não consigo.

```
class Controller{
  constructor(errorAlert){
    this._errorAlert = errorAlert;
  }
  login(login, senha){
    let $ = new Serv();
    $.ajax({
      'url': '/login',
      'type': 'post',
      'responseType': 'json',
      'data': 'login='+login+'&senha='+senha
    }).then(function(resolve){
      let datas = resolve;
      if(datas['loginStatus'] == 1){
        window.location = base_url;
      }else{
          console.log(this._erroAlert);
          view.viewErrorMessage("Usuário ou senha incorreto", this._errorAlert);
      }
    }).catch(function(reject){
      console.log(reject);
    });
  }
}
```

O código funciona perfeitamente, meu único problema é esse do escopo do atributo mesmo.

Erro:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property '_erroAlert' of undefined
>     at Controller.js:19
>     at <anonymous>
> ```

Comment: Tem como colocar o código completo na pergunta, incluindo a mensagem de erro que aparece no `console`?

Comment: Obrigado Tom Melo! Resolve, porém só para se eu capturar o elemento do DOM dentro do construtor, porém quero passar por parâmetro, aconselha algo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que, quando você executa uma função anônima dentro da sua classe, a referência de `this` não é mais para o seu objeto, mas sim para o objeto da requisição AJAX definida por `$.ajax` do jQuery. Ou seja, quando você faz `this._errorAlert` você está tentando acessar o atributo `_errorAlert` da sua requisição, que não existe.

Para contornar isso de maneira fácil, você pode salvar o objeto `this` da sua instância em outra variável antes de fazer a requisição assíncrona:

```
const self = this;
```

E dentro da função anônima, fazer:

```
console.log(slef._erroAlert);
```

Ficando algo como:

```
class Controller{
  constructor(errorAlert){
    this._errorAlert = errorAlert;
  }
  login(login, senha){
    let $ = new Serv();
    const self = this;    // Linha adicionada
    $.ajax({
      'url': '/login',
      'type': 'post',
      'responseType': 'json',
      'data': 'login='+login+'&senha='+senha
    }).then(function(resolve){
      let datas = resolve;
      if(datas['loginStatus'] == 1){
        window.location = base_url;
      }else{
          console.log(self._erroAlert);    // Linha modificada
          view.viewErrorMessage("Usuário ou senha incorreto", self._errorAlert);    // Linha modificada
      }
    }).catch(function(reject){
      console.log(reject);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh não tinha me atentado a isso, obrigado!